# Changing the keyboard layout in Debian 'Unstable'

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout

I recently installed a recent version of [Glade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer) (a GUI editor) to my [Debian 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_11_(Bullseye)) (Bullseye) using -t unstable and it broke the system, whence I upgraded to [Debian 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_12_(Bookworm)) (Bookworm). Now Glade works, but unfortunately, it is no longer possible to change the keyboard layout.

Now I like alphabets, and I've usually got plenty of layouts installed, including, e.g., Hindi, Hebrew, Greek and even Pinyin and Hiragana.

Right now, I've got [IBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) installed (version 1.5.27); I've already tried reinstalling it. Also, I ran IBus settings and played around with the options.

This didn't have any effect whatsoever; apparently *ibus-setup* doesn't even manage the available keyboard layouts.

In *gnome-settings*, there is only one keyboard layout showing (the default one), despite me having enabled additional options in *gnome-tweak-tool*.

I've added some text to */etc/environment* as per *[IBus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IBus)* (Arch Linux wiki), which didn't have any effect.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

你好 again!

I've managed to get it running by using the tool "im-config": I typed

`im-config -n ibus`

into the terminal,

- once as a normal user,
- once after executing the `su` command
- and as `su` once again after executing the `sudo -i` command.

See in particular *[I18n/ibus](https://wiki.debian.org/I18n/ibus)* (Debian Wiki).